# Is $A^TBA$ positive semidefinite, for any square matrix $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Im not sure if $B$ must itself be positive semidefinite; or the statement is true in general (I assume positive semidefinite implies symmetric).

Comment: Think of the scalar $1\times 1$ case. It's true that $a^2 b$ is positive for whatever $b$?

Comment: I saw the property here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties, hence my question. Now, is it necessary/sufficient to have $B$ being positive definite?

Answer (score 2):

It's sufficient: (in the following I assume $B$ is symmetric, and $B\ge0$ means $B$ is positive semidefinite).

$$B\ge 0 \iff \forall x\ne 0:\, x^t B x\ge0 $$
but
$$x^t A^t B A x = y^t By\ge0 \quad {\rm with} \quad y=Ax$$
hence $A^t B A\ge 0$.

(notice that if we change positive semidefinite to strictly positive, we need $A$ non singular to preserve the property)